# Как сделать так что бы задний фон вылезал за контур контейнера

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, background

[image: Пример]

Верстаю на bootstrap. Как сделать так что бы зелёный фон выходил за пределы контейнера. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: ::after ставите 100vw, если у вас контейнер заканчивается у белого пространства, то ставите right: 0. а так предоставьте код, будет проще понять, что у вас на данный момент есть и как вам помочь